# "Cannot read property 'user' of undefined" discord.js issue

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm having an issue with my code for my `discord bot` at the moment I am trying to make my `bot` have the ability to kick users from the server.

Every time I try my code, the error shows:

**Cannot read property 'user' of undefined**

Here is the code:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {

    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'kick':

            const user = msg.mention.user.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = member.guild.member(user);

                if (member){
                    member.kick('You have been kicked from the server').then(() =>{
                        msg.reply(`The user ${user.tag} has been kick from the server`);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        msg.reply(`I was unable to kick this user`);
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                } else {
                    msg.reply(`This user isn\'t in the server`)
                }
            } else {
                msg.reply(`You need to specify a person`)
            }

            break;

    }
})
```

Comment: you have to make user that ```msg``` and ```msg.mention``` are defined first

Comment: It means that `msg.mention` is undefined. I guess you want to use [`mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that it supports `mentions` not `mention`

```
bot.on('message', msg => {

let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

switch (args[0]) {
    case 'kick':

        const user = msg.mentions.user.first();

        if (user) {
            const member = member.guild.member(user);

            if (member){
                member.kick('You have been kicked from the server').then(() =>{
                    msg.reply(`The user ${user.tag} has been kick from the server`);
                }).catch(err => {
                    msg.reply(`I was unable to kick this user`);
                    console.log(err);
                });
            } else {
                msg.reply(`This user isn\'t in the server`)
            }
        } else {
            msg.reply(`You need to specify a person`)
        }

        break;

}
})
```

[image: Discord documentation]

Also see: [Discord official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)